# Is there a way to run lua scripts using awesomewm library?

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I know i can create scripts and import them to the rc file or that i can run keymaps for it.
Can i lets say create a script (script.lua) and run it with my terminal.

I tried running awesome-client on my terminal an passing the script path as the first param `awesome-client scipt.lua` but it throws an error `string "[string "script.lua"]:1: syntax error near <eof>"`.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer changes depending on your AwesomeWM version, but yes, you can.

```bash
# Like this
echo 'require("naughty").notify{text="foo"}' | awesome-client

# Or that
cat myscript.lua | awesome-client

# Or that
awesome-client << EOF
require("naughty").notify{text="foo"}
EOF
```

But keep in mind, this run the code within the main awesome process. It does not "execute the script" as a process.